# Make UserControl remove itself

Tags: c#, user-controls

Does anyone see anything wrong with this:

```
this.Controls.Remove(this);
```

`this` is a class which extends user control.  When I step through this section of code it looks like everything is fine, however nothing happens to the form.  I would expect the control to be gone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned, you're removing the control from itself...that's not likely what you want. I assume you want to remove the control from it's *parent* - so you probably want `this.Parent.Controls.Remove(this);`.

Luckily, since you didn't mention platform, the code is the same for [WebForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.parent.aspx) or [WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Nothing happens because it doesnt find 'this' in the controls collection of 'this'

If your scope is within the Control itself, you would want to do

```
this.Container.Controls.Remove(this);
```

but it all depends on what type of control and in what type of container. but the above should work in most cases.

**EDIT:**

If you know your control belongs to a form, you can do the following, or replace Form with the known container type (i.e. a panel)

```
((Form)this.Container).Controls.Remove(this);
```

Answer (score 4):

Other responses are right to point out that you're not using the correct collection.

However, I will point out that a control which removes itself from the page is not what I would consider "expected behavior" from any asp.net control.  Overriding the `Render` method (or setting the `Visible` property to `false`) would have the same result and with a lot less opportunity to confuse whoever will be maintaining that code in the future.

Comment: this is the code attached to the remove button for this widget...seems like a fair place, but point taken either way

Answer (score 1):

this.Controls is the collection of Controls existing within your usercontrol.  "this" would not exist inside that collection, as "this" is the parent.

I think you want to find the form object, and do myForm.Controls.Remove(this).